# Swift: UIView.insertSubview( , aboweSubview) doesn't work on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, ios8, keywindow

This have been bugging me for some hours now, and i can't seem to find a solution :(.

I have a `UITableView`, and when i click on a row i want to show a detailed information for that row in a "Card". I **add the card in the keywindow** because i want it to be  above the `UINavigationBar`, and have a **transparent view** in the background of the card

This is how my code looks like

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.vwCard.removeFromSuperview()

    let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    vwTransparentView = UIView(frame: screen)
    vwTransparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    vwTransparentView.hidden = true
    vwTransparentView.userInteractionEnabled = false

    keyWindow?.addSubview(self.vwCard)
    keyWindow?.insertSubview(self.vwTransparentView, belowSubview: self.vwCard)


    vwCard.center = CGPointMake((screen.width/2), (screen.height/2))
    vwCard.hidden = true

    vwCard.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
}
```

When I click on `UITableView` row this happens

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    vwCard.hidden = false
    vwCard.alpha = 0
    vwTransparentView.alpha = 0
    vwTransparentView.hidden = false
    vwCard.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.vwCard.alpha = 1
        self.vwCard.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        self.vwTransparentView.alpha = 0.4
    })

}
```

This is how the screen looks like in iOS 7 (7.1)

[image]

And this is how it looks in iOS 8 (8.3)

[image]

I want it to look the same way in iOS 8 as it does in iOS 7. I dont know why `keyWindow?.insertSubview(self.vwTransparentView, belowSubview: self.vwCard)` is not working. I have also tried it the other way around with `insertSubview( ,aboweView:)`

Comment: Now that i upload the images i notice the position of the views is different. Maybe the vwCard doesnt get removed from the superview?

Comment: Why don't you make that card on the storyborad, take an IBOutlet and make it hidden initially and then you can just unhide it whenever you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what i had to was to move the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Also i added the line `vwCard.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.vwCard.removeFromSuperview()

    let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    vwTransparentView = UIView(frame: screen)
    vwTransparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    vwTransparentView.hidden = true
    vwTransparentView.userInteractionEnabled = false

    keyWindow?.addSubview(self.vwCard)
    keyWindow?.insertSubview(self.vwTransparentView, belowSubview: self.vwCard)


    vwCard.center = CGPointMake((screen.width/2), (screen.height/2))
    vwCard.hidden = true
    vwCard.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)

    vwCard.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
}
```